# How to check the property value of the singleton(or static) class in the XAML?

Tags: wpf

There may be expressions that sound rude because I'm not a native English speaker.
I hope you to understand.

I am creating an application supporting the theme.
I would like to change the image in the XAML whenever the theme changes.

Currently, my requirements were implemented by using both cs code and XAML code as below.

```
<HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type models:SolutionStruct}" ItemsSource="{Binding Projects}">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Image Source="{Binding Converter={converters:ToImageByThemeConverter}, ConverterParameter='Solution'}"  Width="16" Height="16" Margin="0 0 5 0">
        </Image>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
    </StackPanel>
</HierarchicalDataTemplate>
```

The below code is the cs code to convert.

```
public class ToImageByThemeConverter : MarkupExtension, IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        string result = string.Empty;

        if (Theme.ThemeKind == ThemeKind.Dark)
        {
            if (parameter.ToString() == "Solution") result = "/Resources/solution.png";
            else if (parameter.ToString() == "Project") result = "/Resources/project.png";
        }

        return result;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider) => this;
}
```

The above code works well but I would like to implement the equal functionality by using only XAML code.

I think If I can check the property value of the Theme class then I can solve it.
Here are some of the vague codes that I hit upon to solve this problem. (not operate)

```
<HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type models:SolutionStruct}" ItemsSource="{Binding Projects}">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Image Width="16" Height="16" Margin="0 0 5 0">
            <Image.Triggers>
                <Trigger Binding Source="{Binding {x:Static Theme}, Path="{ThemeKind}"} Value="Dark">
                    <Setter Source="/Resources/solution_dark.png"/>
                </Trigger>
            </Triggers>
        </Image>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
    </StackPanel>
</HierarchicalDataTemplate>
```

Of course, the above code does not operate because I design vaguely.

Is it possible to design a code that operates with a similar feel to the above code?

or if you have another way to solve this problem please let me know, I don't obsess my way.

Thank you for reading.

Comment: First of all, you should use `DataTrigger` instead of `Trigger`. Second, your binding has incorrect syntax, please have a look at existing [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53589290/datatrigger-is-not-binding-to-a-global-static-property) for proper declaration. And the last point - according to [msdn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.datatrigger.value?view=netframework-4.8#exceptions) data trigger value doesn't support expressions or other binding, I'm sure that you achieve your goal. The solution with converter looks good

Comment: Thank you for advice. I try to create static resources that image path defined by the theme to solve this problem. But also I would think about the way to solve by using DataTrigger following your advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can bind to `static` properties by enclosing the property path in parentheses.
Adding the corresponding `DataTrigger` to the `DataTemplate` the `HierarchicalDataTemplate` would become:

```
<HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type models:SolutionStruct}"
                          ItemsSource="{Binding Projects}">
  <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
    <Image x:Name="Image" 
           Source="/Resources/solution.png" />
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
  </StackPanel>

  <HierarchicalDataTemplate.Triggers>
    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=(Theme.ThemeKind)}" Value="{x:Static ThemeKind.Dark}">
      <Setter TargetName="Image" Property="Source" Value="/Resources/solution_dark.png" />
    </DataTrigger>
  </HierarchicalDataTemplate.Triggers>
</HierarchicalDataTemplate>
```